# Bug in flutter_mobile_vision?

Tags: android, flutter, computer-vision

I wrote a code which uses flutter_mobile_vision and morse to scan texts via mobile camera and covert those scanned texts into Morse code.
Here is my code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_mobile_vision/flutter_mobile_vision.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';
import 'package:morse/morse.dart';

class OCRPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OCRPageState createState() => _OCRPageState();
}

class _OCRPageState extends State<OCRPage> {

  int _ocrCamera = FlutterMobileVision.CAMERA_BACK;
  String _text = "TEXT";

  Future<Null> _read() async {
    List<OcrText> texts = [];
    try {
      texts = await FlutterMobileVision.read(
        camera: _ocrCamera,
        waitTap: true,
      );

      setState(() {
        _text = texts[0].value;
      });
    } on Exception {
      texts.add( OcrText('Failed to recognize text'));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Center(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Lottie.asset('assets/scan-some-words.json', repeat: false),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          Text(_text, style: GoogleFonts.orbitron(textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)), textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          Text(Morse(_text).encode(), style: GoogleFonts.orbitron(textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
          SizedBox(height: 30),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: _read,
            child: new Text('Start Scanning'),
            // color: Color(0xFFFF16CD),
            // splashColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          Text('Tap on the text to convert into Morse Code', style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffE6BBFC)),)
        ]

      )
    );


    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

Running this code returns the error

> E/AndroidRuntime(24295): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Thread$State java.lang.Thread.getState()' on a null object reference
> E/AndroidRuntime(24295): at io.github.edufolly.fluttermobilevision.ui.CameraSource$FrameProcessingRunnable.release(CameraSource.java:1142)
> E/AndroidRuntime(24295): at io.github.edufolly.fluttermobilevision.ui.CameraSource$FrameProcessingRunnable.access$900(CameraSource.java:1119)
> E/AndroidRuntime(24295): at io.github.edufolly.fluttermobilevision.ui.CameraSource.release(CameraSource.java:334)
> E/AndroidRuntime(24295): at io.github.edufolly.fluttermobilevision.ui.CameraSourcePreview.release(CameraSourcePreview.java:85)
> E/AndroidRuntime(24295): at io.github.edufolly.fluttermobilevision.util.AbstractCaptureActivity.onDestroy(AbstractCaptureActivity.java:124)
> E/AndroidRuntime(24295): at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:8251)
> E/AndroidRuntime(24295): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1364)
> E/AndroidRuntime(24295): at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5290)

This seems to be a bug, I've added that in `flutter_mobile_vision` github issues... https://github.com/edufolly/flutter_mobile_vision/issues/71
Any idea how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

The [issue](https://github.com/edufolly/flutter_mobile_vision/issues/71) has been [fixed](https://github.com/edufolly/flutter_mobile_vision/issues/76) in module [flutter_mobile_vision_2](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_mobile_vision_2) and null safety has been added